# nmap returns bogon as hostname

Tags: networking, nmap

Earlier today, on my Ubuntu 14.04 I was running

```
nmap 192.168.0.1/24
```

And my machine had a legitimate hostname in the form of [hostname].[wifinetwork]. However, when I run the same command now, my machine's hostname is bogon, which appears to be short for a bogus IP address. I've tried a bunch of keywords around the term bogon but I don't understand what caused this change or how to fix it.

What other commands should I run to better understand this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by multiple networks at my workplace. So, even when I am connected to wifi network A (192.168.x.x/16), wifi network B (192.168.y.y/16) was still holding on to my hostname, which resulted in my machine hostname in wifi network A to be set as bogon.

So, the question now is to figure out how to make a disconnected wifi network forget my hostname to prevent future collisions (or rejoin the old wifi network).

Comment: That would be [a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) but refer back to this question and explain what went wrong.  (and don't forget to come back and accept your own answer in a few days)  **;-)**